# CF9 ORM mapping issue DB error

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion

I am trying to map some ORM entities and properties and what should seem right, I get the following SQL error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error on rename of './reflexgym/user' to './reflexgym/#sql2-36b-30' (errno: 152)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3515)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3447)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1951)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2548)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1605)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1524)
  at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.JRunStatement.executeUpdate(JRunStatement.java:182)
  at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:383)
  at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.drop(SchemaExport.java:358)
  at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:258)
  at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateConfiguration.exportSchema(HibernateConfiguration.java:366)
  at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateConfiguration.initHibernateConfiguration(HibernateConfiguration.java:221)
  at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateConfiguration.<init>(HibernateConfiguration.java:141)
  at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.ConfigurationManager.initConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
  at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateProvider.InitializeORMForApplication(HibernateProvider.java:182)
  at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateProvider.beforeApplicationStart(HibernateProvider.java:85)
  ...
```

Comment: and, have u tried dropping all tables manually first?

Comment: Hi guys think it was dropping tables manually that did the trick. I added some logic to Application.cfc to have ?reload kill/drop tables. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see comments for solution